# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined in template

Tags: angular

I'm trying to insert a picture in profile user component. But there it's showing me a error: that `the 'file' is undefined`. even the profile picture its showing there. In MySQL the file datatype is `MediumBlob()`.
this is the code in `.ts` file:

```
this.userFileServices.getUserPicture(this.userProfile.id).subscribe(data => {
  this.userFile = data;
  console.log(data);

});
```

and code in `.html` is:

```
<img class=" img-circle" src="data:image/png;base64,{{userFile.file}}" 
    width="140" height="140" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;height: 130px;">
```

the picture is set to profile, I can see it, but there is also this kind of error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined`

Answer (score 4):

For your second problem:
the src of the image should be a trusted url you need to inject in your constructor: `private sanitizer: DomSanitizer`
and then :

```
this.userFileServices.getUserPicture(this.userProfile.id).subscribe(data => {
      const imageData = 'data:image/png;base64," + data.file;
      this.imageSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageData);
   });
  })
```

and then in your html:

```
<img class=" img-circle" [src]="imageSrc" width="140" height="140" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;height: 130px;">
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change it to `{{userFile?.file}}` field userFile is undefined before you get your data from the server.

Comment: I just do it, and gives me this error: unsafe:data:image/png;base64,:1 GET unsafe:data:image/png;base64, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: So, render `<img/>` element even when there's no picture? genius.

Comment: Well, it is the reasion of the error message, isn't it? I'm not saying it's the best solution