# Undefined error in Template from API data in Angular

Tags: html, json, angular

I am trying to display values in HTML template from API data. I didn't define all the values in the object. The data is displayed correctly, but it gives me the following error in console.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

If I declare the object in my app with the API properties, it doesn't show me these errors. But, is there a way to do it than declaring each and every object in my app.

For Example:

JSON value returns {cases: 29371419, deaths: 931080, recovered: 21185046}

I am assigning it to my local object after subscribing to the API

```
this.getData().subscribe(res => {
    this.selectedCategory = res;
});
```

and in template as

```
 <p>{{selectedCategory.cases}}</p>
```

It gives me the value, but displays error in console as

> Cannot read property 'cases' of undefined

How to get rid of this error? Any idea?

Here is a stackblitz demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bhk6pw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: If I add selectedCategory = {cases: ''}, I can get rid of the error. I need to know if there is any other way.

Comment: Duplicate of [ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830616/error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-file-of-undefined-in-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the api call is arrived, there is no `cases` property on your `selectedCategory`.
You need to change your template to this:

```
{{selectedCategory?.cases}}
```

Working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bhk6pw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: awesome. that works.